# mysql stored procedure input parameter values

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, parameters

In MySQL stored procedures, is there any way to get input parameters and their values? I can get the parameter names from information_schema.parameters. But I also want to know the parameter values at run time.
The reason I want to get this is I have a large number of stored procedures. The first thing I want to do in every stored procedure is log input parameter values passed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SELECT IN_VAR_PARAM,This will print IN_VAR_PARAM input parameter on screen.If there is multiple input parameter then you can track them using same statement.
**OR** you can try with Log table.Just create simple LOG table and make entry of all input parameter one by one.
After complete execution of Procedure you can track all variable's value in LOG table.

Comment: Then whats happens??

Comment: I already have a log table and I can write insert into log_table(log_comment) values (concat('param1:',param1,' param2:', param2....) But in this case I will have to write the statement in all the procedures, taking care not to miss any parameters anywhere. If there is any way to programatically know the list of parameter values (like argv[] in C), it can make the the job easier and error free

Comment: I think this is the only way to debug Storedprocedure and Function,still some other options are available then i may be don't know.